# copy value not formula of column vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with values i try to copy...

Let's say the value of A33 is  1655, formula for the cell is IFERROR('L-Logic'!G14;"") and when copied it displays 0 and if i cklick on that copied cell it displays the formula. why is that? Should i have to paste special values? Any suggestions?

Am I on the right path? And if I wan't to check cells values, I was thinking to use this..

If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> "blabla" Then ws.Range("A1:A50" & lastrow).Copy       Destination:=Work

Below is my sample code. Regards

```
For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("List 1", "list 2", "List3"))

        lastrow = Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To lastRow
If ws.cells(i, 1)<> "testtest" Then

         Ws.Range("C1:C50" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Master list").Range("D" & lastRowMaster)
         Ws.Range("A1:A50" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Master list").Range("A" & lastRowMaster)
        Ws.Range("L1:L50" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Master list").Range("B" & lastRowMaster)
         Ws.Range("L1:L50" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Master list").Range("C" & lastRowMaster)
        lastRowMaster = lastRowMaster + Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Rows.Count
         Next i
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like what you did with `lastRowMaster`.

For direct value transfer, you would reverse them.

```
lrm = 1
With Worksheets("MasterList")
    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("List1", "List2", "List3"))
        lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("D" & lrm).Resize(lr, 1) = ws.Range("C1:C" & lr).Value2
        .Range("A" & lrm).Resize(lr, 1) = ws.Range("A1:A" & lr).Value2
        .Range("B" & lrm).Resize(lr, 1) = ws.Range("L1:L" & lr).Value2
        .Range("C" & lrm).Resize(lr, 1) = ws.Range("L1:L" & lr).Value2
        lrm = lrm + Range("A1:A" & lr).Rows.Count
    Next

    '...

End With
```

The destination needs to be resized to accommodate the value transfer. It is not sufficient to just reference the top cell like copy and paste. Be careful with the ones that start at row 7. You will have to do a little maths to get the [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But how can i check values of the cells? like ws.Range("C1:C" & lr).Value2 <> "test"?

Comment: You would have to loop through the data or use a formula and ultimately revert that formula to the values it returned.

Comment: I used With statement on mastersheet and filter the data.